# Where do our thoughts come from?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, theology, practical-kabbalah

Source:

https://nehoraschool.com/are-our-thoughts-ours/

Are there any torah or talmudic sources for the statements in this article here?:

Rabbi Yehuda Leib Ashlag, the great master Kabbalist, teaches that **our thoughts do not originate from us, they come to us from God.**

The truth is, that it is God who sends even the most subtle of thoughts into our minds, and is through this means that He motivates us, moving us to act through the thoughts He sends us. It is through this means that He motivates us and moves us.

until a thought has entered our minds, we cannot actually think it. And once it is in the domain of our minds, it feels like it is ours.

God sends us thoughts one after the other, in a tailor- made sequence, in order to move each one of us further along the path that will bring us into affinity of form with Him and thus enable us to receive all the good and delight that God purposes for each and every one of us.

So God sends to us a series of thoughts and feelings, **both good and bad**. Thoughts and feelings, which are organized according to the  Divine providence, tailored uniquely and intimately for every one of us to bring us to the fulfilment of our soul’s purpose. No one shall be left out, as it is written in Samuel II 14:14 “even the banished one shall not be cast out.”

Pri Chacham Sichot.

Comment: "Please tell me if you agree or disagree with the statements in this article here" - I am of the opinion that this is not suitable for Mi Yodeya, since this is opinion-based. Please consider editing your question to clarify the problem. Do you have trouble with this explanation, do you need explanations on this concept etc...?

Comment: Are there any Torah or Talmudic sources for the statements in this article here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say simply - yes they come from G-d would be an oversimplification.

The Piacezna Rebbe says straight up in his [Hachsharas HaAvreichim](https://www.sefaria.org/Hakhsharat_HaAvrekhim.8.21?ven=The_preparation_of_the_Avreichim,_translated_and_Annotated_by_Betzalel_Edwards,_2022&lang=bi) explains yes for the most part, assuming we are living a meaningful, Jewish life:

> וכיון שרצוננו, מחשבותינו, שמחתנו, וכל נטיותינו, מאת ד׳ המה, לכן רק מי שבדרכי ד׳ ותורתו הולך, אמיתיות הם, והאיש המתרחק מנו ותורתו ח״ו, אז רצונו, מחשבתו, שמחתו, וכל נטיותיו, בדויות הן שקר אבדן ומות ר״ל. צריכים אנו לשמוח בד׳ ובתורתו, בחיינו ובאורך ימינו, מפני שכן חקק ד׳ בנו, ומכל שכן אנחנו שבחר בנו להיות בניו ועבדיו, וקדשנו במצותיו ותורתו, שכל עבודתנו בשמחה תהי׳. ומה שמחתנו, ומה שמחת ישראל בכלל בעולם, כמו שאמר הפסוק [ישעי׳ כ״א] ״שוש אשיש בד׳ תגיל נפשי באלקי, בו ית׳ ותורתו שמחתנו וששוננו
>
> Since all of our desires, thoughts, joys, and inclinations come from God, therefore all of these are only true for one who walks in God’s path and in the ways of His Torah. And if a man, Heaven forbid, distances himself from God and the His Torah, then all of his desires and thoughts, joys and inclinations, are a fiction, a lie, meaningless, and dead. All of our lives and the length of our days we need to rejoice in God and in His Torah, simply because God legislated his laws into our very lives, carving them into our very DNA. And how much more will rejoice in all of our Avodas Hashem when we know at the deepest level that God chose us to be His sons and His servants, to live a life hallowed by His commandments and His Torah! What is our simchah, and what is the simchah of Israel in the world at large? It is as we find written in the verse (Yeshayahu, 61), “I will surely rejoice in Hashem, and my soul will be gladdened in my God.” Our joy is in God, may He be blessed, and His Torah is our simchah and our delight.

Yet, the [Ishbitzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Yosef_Leiner) in his [Mei HaShiloach on Vayeshev](https://www.sefaria.org/Mei_HaShiloach%2C_Volume_I%2C_Genesis%2C_Vayeshev.1?ven=Living_waters,_the_Mei_HaShiloach._Trans._and_edited_by_Betsalel_Philip_Edwards,_Jerusalem,_J._Aronson_2001_%5BRevised_digital_edition,_2021%5D&lang=bi) says that it seems not so straightforward:

> היינו כל המעשים הנעשים בעולם נראים למעשה בשר ודם, אך מההרהור והמחשבה נראים שהם מעשה הש"י. ובאלו הפרשיות מלמד אותנו הש"י אשר המעשים הם מיד הש"י והמחשבות הם מצד האדם וכל המעשים שיעשה האדם דבר רשות  על זה נאמר (ברכות ל"ג:) כי הכל בידי שמים. ומעשה המצות או היפך הם ביד הש"י ורק לפעמים יתלה אותם באדם
>
> All the actions done in the world seem to be the actions of flesh and blood, but ideas and thoughts seem to come from God. But in these Parshiot God teaches us that it is the actions are in the hands of God and thoughts come from man, and all the actions that man does are only those that he is given leave to do, as it is written in the Gemara (Berachot, 33b), “all is in the hands of Heaven.” So, the performance of a commandment or the opposite is in the hands of God, and only occasionally does He make the performance of a commandment dependent on man.